# What is a composition of two binary relations geometrically?

Tags: matrices, geometry, computational-geometry, polygons, function-and-relation-composition

the composition was  defined as follow:

```
(a,b) \in (R;S) <=> there is c | (a,c) \in R  and (c,b) \in S .
```

If our two relations R and S are two convex polygon

Is there a geometric interpretation of the composition of two convex polygon ?
for example :
[image]

the green polygon was the result of composition.
How can i describe geometrically the result !!!

Comment: Can you write some more background please? How is a convex polygon a relation and on which set?

Comment: @PeterFranek A relation is defined by a binary matrix, well these matrix have a specification because the area of 1's in these matrix are convex i.e. all 1's in rows, columns, diagonals and anti-diagonals are consécutifs. So a point (i,j) in polygon associated to the matrix R for exemple is an M[i,j]=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will attempt an answer given the following considerations:

1. Elements (i.e $a$, $b$) are seen as points on axes (on some vector space)
2. A (binary) relation $R$ is seen as defining pairs on the vector space

In this sense each (binary) relation $R$ defines a region (or "area" or "surface") on this vector space,
by defining which points of the space (i.e ordered pairs of $(a,b)$) belong to it.

So in this sense also, the composition of 2 (binary) relations $R \circ S$ defines a region of the space which is the intersection of the two regions defined by $R$ and $S$, plus all the points (of $R$ and $S$) which *lead to* or *away from* these intersection points

Comment: I agree with you that the intersection points are contained in RoS, but which point must be added to them to obtain all points of RoS !!!

Comment: @Limeme90, plus all the points of $R$ which *lead to* and all the points of $S$ that *lead away from* these intersection points

Comment: M, But from the définition of the composition , RoS may contain some point off from S and R;
for example: (1,3) \in R and (3,5) \in S.

the Point (1,5) not contained in (R and S).

Comment: @Limeme90, hmm, yes, however if one wanted to draw a line or connect these points, the connection should necesarrily pass through the intersection points. Maybe this is not the best explanation :-?