# Geometric description of composition of two convex polygons?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, convex-analysis, relations, function-and-relation-composition

The composition was defined as follow:

$(a,b)$ $\in$ $(R;S)$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists c |  (a,c) \in  R \\  $&$ (c,b)  \in S$ .

Also the composition was defined as the binary product of two matrix .

**$SoR$ (relation of composition)$  = R * S $ (product of matrices) where the sum is the disjunction and the product is the conjunction.**

If our two relations R and S are two convex polygon

Is there a geometric interpretation of the composition of two convex polygon ? for example :

[image]

The Green polygon was the searched result .

Comment: It is poor etiquette to post the same question on two different Math.SE sites---even worse when the question is so off-topic in one forum that it is migrated *over to the other forum*. Please do not do that again.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1174196/what-is-a-composition-of-two-binary-relations-geometrically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a geometric interpretation, you're going to have to look at it in three dimensions. That will make some pretty pictures, but I hope you will forgive me for not drawing them.

Ignore your figure on the left, which overlays $R$ and $S$. That's just going to confuse you, because in three dimensional representation they are going to sit on different pairs of axes.

Instead, let $\bar{R}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the prism obtained by placing $R$ on the $(a,c)$ plane $b=0$, and then extruding it along the $b$ direction. Similarly, let $\bar{S}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be the prism obtained by placing $S$ on the $(c,b)$ plane ($a=0$), and extruding it along the $a$ direction. Mathematically, you're doing this:
$$\bar{R} = \{(a,b,c)~|~(a,c)\in R\}, \quad
\bar{S} = \{(a,b,c)~|~(c,b)\in S\}.$$

Now you have two prisms in 3-space that will possibly intersect. Take that 3-dimensional intersection, and *project it* onto the $(a,b)$ axis. Mathematically, that is this:
$$(R;S) = \{(a,b)~|~\exists c~(a,b,c)\in\bar{R}\cap\bar{S}\}.$$

Comment: @Michael_Grant Thanks a lot for your response. excuse me but for the last equation (R;S) = ... it is a union or intersection opérator between the prism R and S?

Comment: Intersection! Sorry.

Comment: @Michael_Grant :thank you enormously for your answer. really thanks. so to do composition opération we need to calculate the intersection of two prisms, and project the result on (a, b). there exists an algorithm that calculates the intersections of two polytopes in 3D?

Comment: I do not know. I assumed you simply wanted a conceptual geometric understanding of what was happening. In an optimization context, I wouldn't even bother with the geometry. I just create a couple of extra variables and everything will work out just fine.